# Plucking from an Associated Model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, postgresql

I have two models, `User` and `Post`. `Post` belongs to `User`. `User` has a field titled `name`. I want to pluck the names of users. I was thinking of doing something like this.

```
some_cool_posts = Post.limit(5)

some_cool_posts.map(&:user).pluck(:name)
```

Unfortunately, pluck doesn't work with arrays so then I do

```
some_cool_posts.map(&:user).map(&:name)
```

I'm wondering is there a faster way to do this in Rails?

Comment: Try: `User.first.posts.pluck(:message)`

Comment: Hmm. What if I want to find the users names of the a list of posts I have?

Comment: What is some_cool_posts?

Comment: An array of records of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 requests to db, if use includes() then you will have two requests

```
some_cool_posts = Post.includes(:users).limit(5)
some_cool_posts.map(&:user).map(&:name)
```

And you can get posts with usernames, for one request, like:

```
some_cool_posts = Post.joins(:user).select('posts.*, users.name as user_name').limit(5)
some_cool_posts.map &:user_name
```

and, imho, the most faster way:

```
some_cool_posts = Post.limit(5)
uids = some_cool_posts.map &:user_id
User.where(id: uids).pluck :name
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. If no one else answers in a day or two I'll reward you the credit. It would be nice to see what the benchmarks are between the different choices.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can also do:

```
@posts_users = some_cool_posts.collect {|post| post.user }
@users_names = @posts_users.collect { |user| user.name }
```

and you can try shortening it to this, but i'm not sure this will work:

```
@users_names = some_cool_posts.collect {|post| post.user }.collect { |user| user.name }
```

Comment: I cleaned up my question a bit and changed it around to reflect the situation I'm in.